# In memory - Distributed parallel processing using Jenkins

Tags: memory, jenkins, parallel-processing, distributed

I have 3 agents in a Jenkins cluster. All the three nodes have to run the same build in parallel. My build has to do the following two things:

1) It has to check the device status (available/locked).

2) Based on the device status: if the device is available, it has to lock the device and then schedule the device for some other actions.

Now, all the 3 nodes have to check the device status in parallel.

My question is:

If one node (`agent1`) locks a device (ex: `dev1`), how can I achieve that other nodes (`agent2` or `agent3`) are getting the particular device (`dev1`) status as locked in Jenkins?

Comment: What kind of device are you talking about?

Comment: device is router..

Comment: All routers I've seen so far (even those for home use) supplied service URLs to retreive status information. If a build mustn't run in case the router is locked you could evaluate the info with the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).